# VS2015 - SSRS 2016 Shared Dataset

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2016

I am having an issue with VS2015 using SSDT to build new reports (SSRS 2016). When using a Shared Dataset and referencing that in the report, it does not work and gives a very vague error. I am connecting to a SQL 2008 R2 database for the dataset.

> An error occurred during local report processing.
>
> The definition of the report '/Dataset1' is invalid.

As soon as I change the dataset to be an embedded dataset, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing (I am using SSRS-2014; everything else is the same). I get the same issue whether my data source is 2008-R2 or 2014. I suspect this is an issue with VS rather than SSRS. Are you able to deploy your reports, and if so, will they work from the server?

Comment: I just upgraded to from the Preview version of SSDT to the current version and the issue persists.

Comment: Its turns out that the Name attribute of the shared dataset was missing as per @yelxe. After implementing his workaround, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the XML for your **shared dataset**. Does it have a **Name** attribute? If not, try this workaround:

Replace

```
<DataSet>
```

with

```
<DataSet Name="Dataset1">
```

Rebuild your solution and try to preview the report.

**IMPORTANT: If you make any changes to the dataset using Visual Studio, the attribute will be removed.**

Hopefully this will do until Microsoft releases a fix.

If you wish, you can add a PowerShell script to your solution that will fix your files for you. You will need the following command for each shared dataset:

```
(Get-Content MyProject\MySharedDataset.rsd).Replace('<DataSet>', '<DataSet Name="MySharedDataset">') | Set-Content MyProject\MySharedDataset.rsd
```

Make sure you have PowerShell Tools for VS 2015.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this @yelxe, this solved my problem.

Comment: is this a VS2015 issue only? I have never experienced this in the past using VS2012.

Comment: My guess would be that the issue was introduced very recently, or we would be able to find many more reported incidents for a basic feature defect like this. Since I jumped from BIDS-2008 to SSDT-2015, I can't say for sure.

Comment: Ah ok. Thought as much yes. I've never encountered it before. Thanks for the help once again.

Comment: Good find. I really hope they address this soon.